# MySQL delete row if not verified in 24 hours

Tags: mysql

I am creating a signup system for a site I am developing and I have hit a small problem. I want the user to have to click a link sent to them via email for their account to become active. When the user is active the row will have the `active` column set to `1`.

When the user signs up the time will be stored and then the email sent. I want it so that their if they don't click the link within 24 hours the user row is removed automatically.

Of course, this means each row needs to be deleted at different times, not just at a certain time delete all the rows that are older than 24 hours.

I am using PHP and MySQL for this site so any answers would need to accommodate for that.

So essentially, after 24 hours after the row was created I want it to be removed *if* the `active` column is `0` (default). When they activate their account the background task (or whatever does the deleting) could cancel the pending request to check the row.

I have heard of 'Cron Jobs', however they run a task every `x` time, I would prefer if the task was run relative to the row. If you think this is incorrect practise do let me know and I will look into using Cron Jobs instead.

Comment: What sort of traffic are you expecting? Approximately how often, on average, would these cleanup tasks need to fire?

Comment: Well, I want to make it as scalable as possible. But I have no idea how many people would be signing up. Perhaps a Cron Job that fires every hour would be best as opposed to a system that keeps track of each row?

Comment: I think a better pattern would be to just have your queries of the table exclude rows that you would consider to be "deleted". modify your queries to add a predicate in the where clause, or add an anti-join... so that the query only returns rows you consider valid. then the deletion of old rows isn't as time critical. you could schedule the deletion process to run on a separate schedule, daily, weekly, hourly, every four hours, of whatever. that's the approach i would take. (if your busy hour for new signups is 1pm to 2pm everyday, do you want to make 1pm to 2pm the busy hour for deletes too?)

Comment: I'm not understanding why there's a need to delete the rows after 24 hours. onesy-twosy deletes are going to add load to the database. (for myisam, additional exclusive table locks blocking other sessions from using the table.). For innodb, additional transactions, obtaining row locks, writing rollback, maintaining the pre-change version of the block,  recording the changes in the log. i'd much prefer to perform deletes less often, as a batch operation.

Comment: Because usernames/emails are not reusable (prevents signup if already used), I could make it so that when it checks for things like that accounts that are 'to be deleted' at the end of the month are simply ignored and then, as you said the deletion is not time critical.

Username repeats won't matter if they are to be deleted. I guess using views would simplify the process of performing queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks on the link, we assume that this table is going to be checked, for example, to see of the user has already clicked on the link an hour ago, and already activated their account.

```
 SELECT s.foo
   FROM signup s
  WHERE s.unique_link_identifier = ?
    AND s.active = 1
```

Or, you are going to check for a matching row that isn't expired...

```
 SELECT s.foo 
   FROM signup s
  WHERE s.unique_link_identifier = ? 
    AND s.active = 0
    AND s.emailsentdate > NOW() + INTERVAL -24 HOUR
```

You could combine the two SELECTs into a single query

```
 SELECT a.active
      , a.foo
   FROM signup a
  WHERE a.unique_link_identifier = ? 
    AND a.active = 1
  UNION ALL
 SELECT s.active
      , s.foo 
   FROM signup s
  WHERE s.unique_link_identifier = ? 
    AND s.active = 0
    AND s.emailsentdate > NOW() + INTERVAL -24 HOUR
```

The point is, you could write your queries so it doesn't matter if the row is deleted exactly 24 hours after the `emailsentdate`. Your queries could be written so it looks like the row isn't there, as if it had been deleted.

The actual deletes could be scheduled to run as a low priority task. That is, there wouldn't be any need for a requirement that rows would have to deleted at a specific time.

Consider this... if the database is down for maintenance, what happens to those scheduled tasks that should have run at the time the database was down. Do they get skipped, or do they all start running when the database comes back up? That whole idea just sounds like a recipe for unintended consequences, and not all of those consequences good.

Comment: Right, I think this is how I will do it. Running the delete statement every month. I may use views to simplify queries that only target signups that are not 'to be deleted' (not verified and older than 24 hours). Thanks!

Comment: @Harry: be very careful with views. Those can have some significant performance implications with large sets. (I'm *not* issuing a recommendation "don't ever use views". I'm just saying that many are unaware of how views get processed in MySQL, and how that it differs from other databases... MySQL materializes the view query as an intermediate table. Predicates from the outer query don't get pushed into the view query. So a very innocuous looking query can wind up creating a copy of a huge table, and then look through that whole un-indexed copy for a couple of rows.

Comment: @Harry: you should consider scheduling a delete process to run nightly. That way, each time it runs it should be handling a reasonably sized set, one day's worth, of uncompleted signups. If the task gets skipped, the next run will have only two days worth. Running a single delete statement to remove hundreds of thousands of rows can crank a *long* time, obtaining and holding a bloatload of concurrency killing row and index locks, blocking other tasks from performing inserts and updates.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a cron job to delete the row and run it once a day, or perhaps once per hour -- if you really want the rows deleted.

However, what you should really do is set up a view that only shows legitimate users (or you can add this logic to any query that accesses the table):

```
create view v_signups as
    select s.*
    from signups s
    where s.active = 1 or
          s.emailsenttime >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);
```

Then, use this view (or equivalent logic) in your code to see the "valid" signups.

Even if you have a cron job, you'll still want to maintain this logic.  The job would run at a fixed schedule.  Even once an hour means that some users will hang around for 25 hours and others for 24 hours.  And, things can happen.

The view guarantees that all signups are treated equally and protects your logic in the event that the job doesn't run or hangs for some reason.

Comment: I am a little confused as what the view does. Users that have validated would have `active` set in their user row. What does the view accomplish?

I should mention I have only briefly read about views, never actually used one.

Comment: @Harry: for the issue at hand, the view is probably a distraction. You don't need a view to implement this logic.  The queries that select fomr the signups table can include a conditional check...   if the emailsenttime is older than 24 hours, don't include the row.  Or, to put that the other way around, if the emailsenttime is later than now() minus 24 hours, return the row. Just figure out the query that excludes the rows you consider to be deleted. Then your "delete" task doesn't have to run every minute to keep the table up-to-date. It's your query of the table that excludes the rows.

Comment: Excluding the rows isn't my goal, I want them removed from the table so it isn't filled with inactive accounts.

I am already ignoring accounts that aren't `active`. If I ever need to list accounts, then I will likely include a conditional as you said.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a few extra accounts in the table.  Even if you have 10 per second, one day's worth would be less than a million -- and the "clutter" would have little impact on performance.

Comment: I concur with Gordon. Running a bloatload of delete transactions bunch of individual delete statements is going to impact performance

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) for this. There are two ways you could go:

1. If you expect to regularly clean up more than one record every hour (an entirely arbitrary division) you could create a repeating task that runs every hour to delete all non-active records more than 24 hours old.

   ```
   CREATE EVENT hourly_inactive_cleanup
     ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
     DO
       DELETE FROM signups
         WHERE emailsenttime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOURS)
           AND active = 0;
   ```
2. If a periodic job would regularly execute without deleting any records, you could, at insert time, create a task (possibly by means of a trigger) that will fire after 24 hours to delete that record if it's not active. (It should actually delete *all* target records, just in case the previous event failed for some reason.)

   ```
   CREATE EVENT some_event_name
     AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 HOURS
     DO
       DELETE FROM signups
         WHERE emailsenttime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOURS)
           AND active = 0;
   ```

although I confess I'm stumped as to how to generate a unique event name for this method.

Comment: Is creating a job per user row good practise? I assume I would name the job using a standard format (perhaps <username>_timer) and when the link is clicked in the email the job is cancelled.

Comment: As I said, it depends on how often your cleanup task would run without deleting any records. Frequent unneeded runs would be more of a drain on resources than storing a few extra events in the schedule table.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point.

I think I will try this and get back when I have completed it. Thanks.

Seeing as though the users 'username' and 'uid' are unique, I could use that in the name of the event.

Comment: @Harry It might actually not be possible to do this using a trigger; you might have to use a call from the application to schedule the event.

Comment: Well, my plan was to create the event from the PHP file that handles the registration (after the email was submitted successfully). Would this work?

Comment: @Harry I've never tried it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It seems like the DELETE statements in these examples would *keep* rows that are over 24 hours old, and *remove* rows that are less than 24 hours old. But aside from that, this approach of scheduling individual tasks to delete rows at a specific time seems like it is designed to address a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @spencer7593 You're right about the dates; I always muck that up. As for the per-row scheduling, I'm not sure what you mean, although I admit it might be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: This answers the question that was asked. My concerns are the number of events that will be scheduled. Those get stored in the `event` table in the `mysql` database, which is (still) implemented as a myisam table. That means an exclusive table lock is taken whenever a  DML operation is performed... adding an event is going to do an insert, removing an event is a delete. So this approach is inserting and deleting rows from the `event` table. I'm leery of unnecessary DML on the myisam tables in the mysql database, I avoid it where I can.

Comment: @spencer7593: "...is (still) implemented as a myisam table." I was unaware of this. So the per-record delete event would probably be counterproductive if there were more than a handful of records inserted per day. As an aside, is there any reason `event` couldn't be manually converted to InnoDB?

Comment: Yes, there's a reason tables in the msyql database can't be converted to a different storage engine... MySQL does NOT SUPPORT that. There are code dependencies on MyISAM. I believe work was underway to make that change, to allow a different storage engine, but there's is a lot of nitty-gritty internal MySQL code that depend on those tables. (NOTE: The information I have may be dated. More recent versions of MySQL may allow for some of the tables in mysql database to be converted. But the MySQL Reference Manual I read said to not do it, it's not supported.)